# How to use BERT for performing regression?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow2.0

Here is the [code and dataset](https://github.com/wilsonsujames/BERT_regression)

This is the function used for building the model:

```
def build_regression_model():
    text_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(), dtype=tf.string, name='text')
    preprocessing_layer = hub.KerasLayer(tfhub_handle_preprocess, name='preprocessing')
    encoder_inputs = preprocessing_layer(text_input)
    encoder = hub.KerasLayer(tfhub_handle_encoder, trainable=True, name='BERT_encoder')
    outputs = encoder(encoder_inputs)
    net = outputs['pooled_output']
    net = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1)(net)

    return tf.keras.Model(text_input, net)


regression_model = build_regression_model()
```

The loss is:

```
loss='mean_absolute_error'
```

The optimizer is:

```
optimizer=tf.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.1)
```

Can someone please provide tips to solve this problem. Thank you!

Comment: What seems to be the problem OP?

Comment: the predict answer is all the same value.

Comment: Theoretically, your setup seems right. Did you try to train? What issues did you face?

Comment: when I predict pos and neg review. The result value is all the same value.
I have try  label divided by 10 to between 0-1.
and  change latest output layer activation to sigmoid or relu.
But not help any further.